# Facebook Graph api profile picture URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, url, sdk, profile-picture

I'm trying to display the profile pic of the logged in user but for some reason the url gets changed. This is the function i've put together

```
function testAPI() {
    FB.api('/me','GET',{"fields":"picture{url},name"},function(response) {
        var url = response.picture.data.url;
        console.log(url);
        $("#status").html('<p>'+response.name+'</p><figure id="profilePicture"><img href="'+response.picture.data.url+'"/></figure>');
        console.log(document.getElementById('status').innerHTML);
    });
}
```

the first console log returns:

"[https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/12036592_10153768750487873_8195289030629933305_n.jpg?oh=5488c4b312a1b077b68243a7998d217e&oe=56BA5DE5&**gda**=1454718467_89331767e8555ed196c5559340774fbb](https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/12036592_10153768750487873_8195289030629933305_n.jpg?oh=5488c4b312a1b077b68243a7998d217e&oe=56BA5DE5&__gda__=1454718467_89331767e8555ed196c5559340774fbb)"

the second returns the correct inner html as the users name diplays but its adding amp; after the & symbols in the url so the profile pic isn't displaying. No idea how to fix this. Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have incorrect `<img/>` tag syntax, you should be using `src` instead of `href`

Change:

```
$("#status").html('<p>'+response.name+'</p><figure id="profilePicture"><img href="'+response.picture.data.url+'"/></figure>');
```

To:

```
$("#status").html('<p>'+response.name+'</p><figure id="profilePicture"><img src="'+response.picture.data.url+'"/></figure>');
```